# Separating data from different months in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm using the Google Analytics API to get info from my website and I want to collect info from more than one month at the same time, but the GA functions give me data from only the last month I ask for.

Here's an example:

I request info for dates from 1st of February of 2012 to today, but when I get the information, the API gives me data from 1st to 22th of March and then from 23th to 29th of February.

Is there any solution for sepatating this data and get the whole information?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the request you are sending to the API.

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous, please add more details like: request parameters(dimensions, metrics, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You can add "start-date="  & "end-date" as query string to the request
such as **start-date=2012-07-01&end-date=2012-07-25**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this tool provided by google: http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Just log in with your credentials and you can build your API queries in a simple GUI. Maybe you are just missing something?